# To what extent does the "Cauchy-Schwarz inequality" hold for a normed vector space not inner product space?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

It is known to all that for inner product space $H$, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality hold: $| \langle x,y \rangle | \leq \| x \| \cdot \| y \| \ \forall x,y\in H$, and for a normed space $X$ without inner product structure, we have two similar "Cauchy inequality":1.[real case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2302537/986542)(use some algebraic substitution); 2.[complex](http://mfat.imath.kiev.ua/article/?id=991) [case](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06031)

My question is that for a normed space but not inner product space $X$, noting that $$f(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k(\|x+b_k y\|^2-\|x\|^2-\|b_k y\|^2) \ (a_k,b_k\ne 0,k=1,2,···,n )$$ which satisfy that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\overline{b_k}=1; \ \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k=0 $$in complex case,or
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k=\frac{1}{2}$$ in real case,

***(In summary, for an inner product space there is $f(x,y)=\langle x,y \rangle$ )***

then in addition to the two examples mentioned above, what conditions are satisfied by sequence $\{a_k\},\{b_k\},\{c_k\}$ that enable inequality $|f(x,y)|\le\|x\|\|y\| \ \forall x,y\in X$ to hold?

```
                                                     ----2023.12.17
```

---

Okay, I admit that I asked the question in order to find the condition that makes the normed space $X$ isometric isomorphic to the inner product space, here's [the link to the question I asked on MathOverFlow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/463207/438407). Thank if you can give me any help.

```
                                                     ----2024.02.02
```

---

I'm now focus on a particular case about this problem:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}(\|x+b_{k}y\|^2-\|x-b_{k}y\|^2)$$
where $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}=\frac{1}{2}$, is $|f(x,y)|\le \|x\| \|y\|$ hold?

Anyone who can give a proof of this case might be instructive.

```
                                                     ----2024.02.28
```

Comment: tl;dr. Is the question not just this: When does a norm arise from an inner product? The answer to this question is [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4728315/949989).

Comment: Now I am reading your post a bit closer. Even if you find $a_k,b_k,c_k$ so that $|[x,y]|\le\|x\|\|y\|$ holds: that construct $[x,y]$ that you defined there does not look bilinear in $x,y$ to me, hence it can never ever be an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

Comment: @KurtG.:I edited it for express my question more clearly. I think you misunderstood my question, my question wasn't about how to give the inner products, it was just formally close, perhaps $[x,y]$ is formally misleading, I used $f(x,y)$ instead

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like [semi-inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-semi-inner_product)?

Comment: @Jakobian : Thank, I learned a little bit about semi-inner product. Given that there are infinite varieties of s.i.p. in any normed linear space, the question can then be transformed to whether one can find a proper s.i.p. $[·,·]$ that satisfies $[x,y_f]=f(x,y_f)$, is that what you are referring to?